# Protocol does respondsToSelector not work for me in this case?

Tags: ios, objective-c, protocols

I have a problem to create a protocol the respondsToSelector not calling the method. Maybe someone can see where I'm going wrong.

See my code:

`Protocol.h`

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@protocol CHTumblrMenuDelegate <NSObject>
@required
- (void)dismissView;
@end

typedef void (^CHTumblrMenuViewSelectedBlock)(void);

@interface CHTumblrMenuView : UIView<UIGestureRecognizerDelegate,CHTumblrMenuDelegate>{
    id<CHTumblrMenuDelegate>delegate;
}

@property (nonatomic, weak) id<CHTumblrMenuDelegate> delegate;
```

`Protocol.m`

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame{
     self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
if (self) {
    // Initialization code
    UITapGestureRecognizer *ges = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(dismiss:)];
    ges.delegate = self;
    [self addGestureRecognizer:ges];
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    backgroundView_ = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.bounds];
    //backgroundView_.backgroundColor = TumblrBlue;
    backgroundView_.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(backgroundView_.frame.size);
    [[UIImage imageNamed:@"background"] drawInRect:backgroundView_.bounds];
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    backgroundView_.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:image];

    [self addSubview:backgroundView_];
    buttons_ = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:6];


}
return self;
}

- (void)dismiss:(id)sender{
    NSLog(@"DIS");

    if (delegate == nil) {
       CHTumblrMenuView *vd = [[CHTumblrMenuView alloc]init];
       delegate = vd;
    }
    [delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(dismissView)];

    [self dropAnimation];
    double delayInSeconds = CHTumblrMenuViewAnimationTime  + CHTumblrMenuViewAnimationInterval * (buttons_.count + 1);
    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){

    [self removeFromSuperview];
});
}
```

`ClassUseProtocol.m`

```
CHTumblrMenuView *menuView = [[CHTumblrMenuView alloc] init];
menuView.delegate = self;

-(void)dismissView{
    NSLog(@"DismissView");
}
```

Log:
`2016-06-06 22:44:07.258 ProtocolExample[7513:4030481] DIS`

does anyone have any idea what might be going on?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Your protocol method is @required, So no need to check for

```
 delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(dismissView)
```

In case of un-define dismissView method, you will got compile time error.You can below line

```
 if (self.delegate && [self.delegate conformsToProtocol:@protocol(CHTumblrMenuDelegate)]) {
    [self.delegate dismissView];
 }
```

Comment: The `if` statement in this answer makes no sense. Why would you check to see if `self` conforms to the protocol? There is no reason whatsoever why `self` would conform to the protocol. It's the delegate that needs to conform to the protocol. And it's the delegate that needs to implement the protocol method.

Comment: I have made the code more generic, protocol/ delegate have 1 to 1 relation between VC, So it will make sense to put if condition if your design have VC hierarchy level.

Comment: What you say doesn't make any sense. It is the delegate that conforms to the protocol, not the class with the `delegate` property. In the code in your answer, `self` should *not* conform to the protocol. Only `self.delegate` should conform to the protocol.

Comment: Thanks a lot for rising concern. We are having same obj reference  from line "self.delegated = self" . +conformsToProtocol is a class method so calling class method from same class we can avoid [[self class] conformsToProtocol] to [self conformsToProtocol]. The only thing I missed is to check self.delegate for nil. I will update the self.delegate && [[self class]conformsToProtocol:@protocol(CHTumblrMenuDelegate)]. please conform if I am still missing anything.

Comment: reference for above comment is https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSObject/conformsToProtocol:

Comment: Could somebody please explain why I am getting down vote. I will really try to improve it.

Comment: I've already posted two comments explaining what is wrong. Please see the other non-downvoted answers for the proper solution.

Comment: It's still wrong. 1) No need to see if `self.delegate` is `nil` or not. 2) There is no reason to see if the delegate conforms to the protocol. You should see if the delegate responds to the selector. If the delegate method were optional, it could still conform to the protocol but not implement the method - crash. Even if the delegate method is required, the delegate may implement the method but not conform to the protocol. In that case you end up not calling the method.

Comment: point 1 is optional there is no harm to add this condition . For Point 2 I have clearly mention in answer "protocol method is @required " in that case check for conformsToProtocol: else we have to follow your approach. Could you pls let me know the correct use for conformsToProtocol: method?

Comment: I have made a quick answer, It might not taken care all condition but developer should add the condition as per their need bases. Please mention the correct answer in your comment I will update it.

Answer (score 4):

You aren't doing anything with the result of `respondsToSelector` - this returns a boolean that indicates whether the object responds to the specified selector.  If it returns true then you should invoke the delegate method:-

```
if ([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(dismissView)]) {
    [delegate dismissView];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your usage have some issues. The correctly usage is the following code;

1. Firstly, `self.delegate` can perform this method that implemented by another class which has been comply with this protocol `CHTumblrMenuDelegate`.
2. Secondly, the `dismissView` method which must implement by another class .
   The file `CHTumblrMenuView.h` or `CHTumblrMenuView.m` is either implement the protocol  `CHTumblrMenuDelegate` and the must-implemented method.

   ```
   if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(dismissView)]) {
          [self.delegate dismissView];
   }
   ```

   @interface CHTumblrMenuView  : NSObject
   @end

   @implementation CHTumblrMenuView 
   -(void)dismissView{
      NSLog(@"dismissView");
   }
   @end

Answer (score -2):

you have double define the delegate

```
@interface CHTumblrMenuView : UIView<UIGestureRecognizerDelegate,CHTumblrMenuDelegate>
```

@property (nonatomic, weak) id delegate;